# Oracle query monitoring -

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have Java Code that contain oracle insert,update,etc statement , while executing java program oracle statement executed . I need to Know what is happing in oracle database. How can I achieve It..?

```
    try {
        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Enquiry_PrimaryDetailsId\n"
                + "FROM  enquiry_revisiondetails erevision\n"
                + "WHERE ActiveCode=1 AND Enquiry_RevisionDetailsId NOT IN (SELECT Enquiry_RevisionDetailsId FROM  quotationprimary );";
        proc = dao.prepareCall(sql);
        System.out.println(proc);
        rs = dao.executePreparedCall(proc);
        while (rs.next()) {
            Enquiryentry enquiryentry = new Enquiryentry();
            enquiryentry.setEnquiry_primarydetailsid(rs.getString("Enquiry_PrimaryDetailsId"));

            enquirylist.add(enquiryentry);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        dao.releaseAll();
    }
```

This my Java Coding , I have to know the statement which is runs on oracle.

Comment: What do you mean .. "what is happening"? A lot of things happen in the database, what do you want to look for? What do you want to understand?

Comment: Actually I am looking  query  is currently executing on database (ORACLE) .The query is sent through Java (JDBC)   .